# Fence - task from Polish Informatics Olympiad

Tags: algorithm

Recently I came across a task from Polish Informatics Olympiad called "Fence" and I can't solve it.

The first input line contains integer number `n` (`1 <= n <= 200 000`) and the second line contains `n` numbers (each is not less than `1` and not greater than `10^6`). You have to delete some numbers so that the sum of the remaining ones is as large as possible and the their values have to increase and decrease. I mean, if `A` is a set of remaining numbers and `ai` is `i`-th number from set then `a1 < a2 > a3 < a4 > a5 < a6` etc. or `a1 > a2 < a3 > a4 < a5 > a6` etc.

From range of `n` values, it seems that the complexity of solution would be similar to `O(n log n)`, but I'm not sure about that. I'd be grateful if someone told me the solution.

**Some examples**

Input:

> 2
>   100 90

Output:

> 190

Input:

> 6
>   7 5 4 6 6 5

Output:

> 23

Comment: Hint #1: An optimal solution has a rightmost included element -- so if we find, for each i between 1 and n inclusive, the highest-scoring solution *in which we force the i-th element to be the rightmost included element*, then the best of these n solutions must be the best overall.

Comment: Hint #2: If we break down these subproblems further, so that for each i between 1 and n inclusive we make 2 subproblems -- one in which the i-th element is forced to be the rightmost included element *and bigger than the previous included element*, and one in which the i-th element is forced to be the rightmost included element *and smaller than the previous included element*, we now have 2n subproblems to be solved -- but the advantage is that there is now a way to use optimal solutions to smaller subproblems to optimally solve larger subproblems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Finally I came up with a solution.

I'll create two array (let's say dp_bigger and dp_smaller), the first one for max sum ending on i-th element (when i is bigger than previous included element) and second when i-th element is smaller than previous included element. To calculate dp_bigger[i] I calculate sum of arr[i] (arr is an array with all numbers from input) and the biggest previously calculated sum from dp_smaller at some index j (0 <= j < i).

Of course I have to remember that when I calculate dp_bigger[i] and I've found some dp_smaller[j] with biggest sum I have to check if arr[i]  > arr[j]. I do the same for dp_smaller, but insted I check if arr[i] < arr[j].

Now, if I want to find these max values quickly I will create  two other arrays (called bigger and smaller) filled with zeros each of size 10^6. When I calculate some dp_bigger[i] in bigger[arr[i]-1] I put dp_bigger[i] and the same for dp_smaller[i] so that I can create a range tree on arrays bigger and smaller. Thanks to this when I want to calculate dp_bigger[i] I search for max in array smaller on range from 0 to arr[i]-2 and if I want to calculate dp_smaller i search in bigger on range arr[i] to 10^6.

I think that it's the correct solution and once again thanks for the hints.